# Excel: Find letter in cell range containing strings and count occurrance

Tags: excel, countif

I've got a cell range A1:A10 containing single letters or short strings like "GEPR", "GE" etc. and want to count every cell containing a G.
I tried

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND("G";A1);1);0)
```

but this writes a 1 into each row and doesn't output the sum of cells containing a "G". Furthermore if I want to count for another letter (e.g. "E") I need more space in the worksheet. Is there a more convenient function like `COUNTIF` which just needs one cell for each leter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` together with `FIND` to do this.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--NOT(ISERROR(FIND("G",$A$1:$A$10))))
```

This basically counts for how many values in `A1:A10` the `FIND` function does not return an error.

Comment: Thank you very much. This does exactly what I was looking for. Could you please explain what --NOT does?

Comment: The `--` is basically saying "times -1 twice". This is used to convert the Boolean value returned by `NOT` to a numerical value (`1` or `0`). This is necessary for `SUMPRODUCT` to add up the values without returning an error.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. When I remove the `--`nothing happens. Can you give me a link to the documentation of this? Google doesn't understand `excel function NOT` or `excel meaining --NOT` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't care about case just use `COUNTIF` with "wildcards", e.g. for the number of cells in your range containing a "G"

`=COUNTIF(A$1:A$10,"*G*")`

If you want to use a cell reference for the criterion, e.g. with C2 containing "G" you can use this version:

`=COUNTIF(A$1:A$10,"*"&C2&"*")`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this doesn't seem to work for me with LibreOffice, although I have regular expressions activated.

Comment: I assumed you were using Excel, this would probably be the best approach in Excel - I don't think Libre Office supports wildcards in COUNTIF

Comment: At least it is able to use regular expressions in cells with functions. I tried different reg. expressions but none worked. Maybe it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You might put the letters of interest in Row1 (staring at B) and in B2 and copied across:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(IF(FIND(B$1;$A2:$A11);1);0))
```

entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: Sorry, but with this I get a 6 as result when looking for "G" although there are only 4 G present. I don't know why this is happening, maybe because I'm using Libreoffice.